# Не работает ttf шрифт

Tags: css

```
    @font-face{
    font-family: "dima";
    src: url("dima.ttf") format("ttf");
    }
    body{
    background: #000000;
    max-width: 540px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: dima;
}
```

Шрифт есть лежит в той самой директории.
Но увы не работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
@font-face{
   font-family: "dima";
   src: url("dima.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) Помогли)